# Why does my FAB icon have a black box around it?

Tags: android, material-design, floating-action-button

I created the material floating action button from the android support library and with the add icon from the [material icons site](http://google.com/design/icons) by downloading an archive that contains the png drawables of the icon in 24dp.

This is the code I have created the FAB with:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        app:fabSize="normal"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp">

</android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton>
```

This is how it renders in the xml design tab:

[image]

There hasn't been much I could do cause I have the right xml syntax for the button and the icon is obviously transparent without a black background around it.

Comment: How does it look on the real device? or emulator? Xml looks fine for me

Comment: try this icon https://www.dropbox.com/s/wacsbi3iwxn42nc/ic_plus_white_24dp.rar?dl=0

Comment: I think this issue from used image not from code , your code seem to be nice

Comment: I used the image from the material design icons. google.com/design/icons

Comment: @MinaFawzy thanks! the icons in the link you posted worked!, did you get it from the material design icons site too?

Comment: I got it from graphic designer , I dont know where he go it may be he design it

Comment: The issue seems to be from Android Studio, in my device (Motorola RAZR D3 - Android 4.1.2) and in Windows 10 the black square is transparent.

Answer (score 4):

the issue not from code , it from image itself ,  try use this [icon](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wacsbi3iwxn42nc/ic_plus_white_24dp.rar?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

This is an android studio issue. Try running the app in device and the button might be showing up correctly. More details about this bug - [ic_stop_white_*dp.png background is black, not transparent](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/137)